# How do you eliminate duplicate data displayed in a dropdownlist? In FormView within ASP.net?

Tags: sql, asp.net, html.dropdownlistfor

I am having a little trouble to filter my data to eliminate duplicates. This is a data binding exercise and the question asks "to change Listing Agent ID into a dropdownlist that will display distinct Agent LastName in the edit mode"

My coding follows:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" DataKeyNames="ListingID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="Both">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                ListingID:
                <asp:Label ID="ListingIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ListingID") %>' />
                <br />
                PropertyID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PropertyIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PropertyID") %>' />
                <br />
                ListingAgentID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="ListingAgentIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ListingAgentID", "{0:N}") %>' />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="LastName" DataValueField="ListingAgentID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ListingAgentID", "{0}") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RedwoodConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Listings.ListingAgentID, Agents.LastName, Listings.ListingID, Listings.PropertyID, Listings.SaleStatusID, Listings.BeginListDate, Listings.EndListDate, Listings.AskingPrice, Agents.AgentID FROM Agents INNER JOIN Listings ON Agents.AgentID = Listings.ListingAgentID" UpdateCommand="UPDATE Listings SET ListingAgentID = FROM Listings INNER JOIN Agents ON Listings.ListingAgentID = Agents.AgentID"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <br />
                SaleStatusID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="SaleStatusIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SaleStatusID") %>' />
                <br />
                BeginListDate:
                <asp:TextBox ID="BeginListDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BeginListDate") %>' />
                <br />
                EndListDate:
                <asp:TextBox ID="EndListDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EndListDate") %>' />
                <br />
                AskingPrice:
                <asp:TextBox ID="AskingPriceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AskingPrice") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                ListingID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="ListingIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ListingID") %>' />
                <br />
                PropertyID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PropertyIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PropertyID") %>' />
                <br />
                ListingAgentID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="ListingAgentIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ListingAgentID") %>' />
                <br />
                SaleStatusID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="SaleStatusIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SaleStatusID") %>' />
                <br />
                BeginListDate:
                <asp:TextBox ID="BeginListDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BeginListDate") %>' />
                <br />
                EndListDate:
                <asp:TextBox ID="EndListDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EndListDate") %>' />
                <br />
                AskingPrice:
                <asp:TextBox ID="AskingPriceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AskingPrice") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                ListingID:
                <asp:Label ID="ListingIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ListingID") %>' />
                <br />
                PropertyID:
                <asp:Label ID="PropertyIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PropertyID") %>' />
                <br />
                ListingAgentID:
                <asp:Label ID="ListingAgentIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ListingAgentID") %>' />
                <br />
                SaleStatusID:
                <asp:Label ID="SaleStatusIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SaleStatusID") %>' />
                <br />
                BeginListDate:
                <asp:Label ID="BeginListDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BeginListDate") %>' />
                <br />
                EndListDate:
                <asp:Label ID="EndListDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EndListDate") %>' />
                <br />
                AskingPrice:
                <asp:Label ID="AskingPriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AskingPrice") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="New" Text="New" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" NextPageText="Next" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RedwoodConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Listings] WHERE [ListingID] = @ListingID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Listings] ([ListingID], [PropertyID], [ListingAgentID], [SaleStatusID], [BeginListDate], [EndListDate], [AskingPrice]) VALUES (@ListingID, @PropertyID, @ListingAgentID, @SaleStatusID, @BeginListDate, @EndListDate, @AskingPrice)" SelectCommand="SELECT Listings.ListingAgentID, Agents.LastName, Listings.ListingID, Listings.PropertyID, Listings.SaleStatusID, Listings.BeginListDate, Listings.EndListDate, Listings.AskingPrice, Agents.AgentID FROM Agents INNER JOIN Listings ON Agents.AgentID = Listings.ListingAgentID" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Listings] SET [PropertyID] = @PropertyID, [ListingAgentID] = @ListingAgentID, [SaleStatusID] = @SaleStatusID, [BeginListDate] = @BeginListDate, [EndListDate] = @EndListDate, [AskingPrice] = @AskingPrice WHERE [ListingID] = @ListingID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ListingID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ListingID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PropertyID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ListingAgentID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SaleStatusID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="BeginListDate" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="EndListDate" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="AskingPrice" Type="Decimal" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PropertyID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ListingAgentID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SaleStatusID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="BeginListDate" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="EndListDate" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="AskingPrice" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ListingID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <div>
```

[image: Model Example]

[image: My outcome]

Thanks for your time and your help... I've spent countless hours trying to figure this out!!! :-) you are legendary!!!

Comment: Have you already tried to put a DISTINCT clause in your SQL select command?

Comment: while binding data remove the duplicate from the list. Where is the code for binding data to dropdown?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `distinct` and `group by` in your SqlDataSource by which you are filling dropdown list.

```
SELECT 
    distinct
    Listings.ListingAgentID, 
    Agents.LastName, 
    Listings.ListingID, 
    Listings.PropertyID, 
    Listings.SaleStatusID, 
    Listings.BeginListDate, 
    Listings.EndListDate, 
    Listings.AskingPrice, 
    Agents.AgentID 
FROM 
    Agents 
INNER JOIN 
    Listings 
ON 
    Agents.AgentID = Listings.ListingAgentID
group by
    Listings.ListingAgentID, 
    Agents.LastName, 
    Listings.ListingID, 
    Listings.PropertyID, 
    Listings.SaleStatusID, 
    Listings.BeginListDate, 
    Listings.EndListDate, 
    Listings.AskingPrice, 
    Agents.AgentID
```

Comment: Dear Shekhar I have placed distinct and group by statements in my dropdownlist Select command and it is still not working... It is supposed to go in my selectcommand is that right? Thanks a bunch

Comment: You need to select only those columns which are used in your dropdown list. There may be possibility that due to other column the row is getting distinct.

Comment: I guess Shekhar is right. Try to use a different datasource for your dropdownlist. It should contain only the agent id and agent last name. Hope it helps.